# Ruby array conversion with even indices

Tags: ruby, arrays

With below array:

```
[68, 205, 286, 347, 482]
```

I want to generate something like:

```
[0, 68, 68, 205, 205, 286, 286, 347, 347, 482]
```

What is the best way to accomplish this in Ruby?

Comment: why not the last one repeated ? Is there always the first element as `0`?

Comment: what are the rules for this transformation?  what would `[2, 3, 6, 9]` generate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by other, the logic is not really clear. I would write something like this:

```
array = [68, 205, 286, 347, 482]
first, *middle, last = [0], *array
p first + middle.flat_map{|x|[x,x]} << last
# => [0, 68, 68, 205, 205, 286, 286, 347, 347, 482]
```

Answer (score 3):

If I am guessing right you want to iterate the array with two neighboring elements at a time. There's [`each_cons`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) for that:

```
a = [68, 205, 286, 347, 482]

a.each_cons(2) do |x, y|
  p [x, y]
end

# [68, 205]
# [205, 286]
# [286, 347]
# [347, 482]
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you in fact looking to work through an `Array` of paired values, to work with ranges of values implied by "joining the dots" of the array? This is not how you have phrased the question, but is an implied property of your output:

```
([0]+a).each_cons(2).to_a
 => [[0, 68], [68, 205], [205, 286], [286, 347], [347, 482]]
```

You would then work through the start and end points like this:

```
([0]+a).each_cons(2) do |x,y|
  # x is 0, y is 68 for first iteration
  # So you could have (x...y) as a Range for example
end
```

Or if you really do have your example output as the desired end result, just flatten it:

```
([0]+a).each_cons(2).to_a.flatten
 => [0, 68, 68, 205, 205, 286, 286, 347, 347, 482]
```

Comment: That `0` is making the noise.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [68, 205, 286, 347, 482]

a =  a.zip(a.dup).unshift(0).flatten
a.pop
puts a
# => [0, 68, 68, 205, 205, 286, 286, 347, 347, 482]
```

Comment: `482` only once OP want

Comment: if you want to remove last element add just `.pop`